# correct structure (Database) for a mobile application

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, query-optimization, database-normalization

We are making a mobile application with some friends, but we are having problems regarding the structure of the database due to Unknown.I think it is a good question that can help many people and it would be nice if people with knowledge can explain it well. The app consists of providing various services (more can be added in the future) to customers. They are logged in and have access to our services. At first we thought of a table that contains columns with all the customer data + the services. Then we saw that it was more effective to make another separate table called "services" and that identifies the user by an id. The problem now comes to this table. We do not know whether to make a single column with all services (such as array) or to make one column per service. I took a photo so that what I am proposing can be observed more easily.
[image]

The question is which of these options (obviously there may be a third that we do not contemplate) is the best, in terms of performance.
I think that the second option I see several defects but I'm not sure. In terms of latency and speed, traversing an array (and more if services are added, or perhaps they are out of order because the user first hired service2 and then 1) is much higher than in option 1. In addition, the fact that a user is under a service, that implies going through the entire array, looking for it and eliminating it. I don't know you are the experts, what do you recommend?all this will be uploaded to the cloud (azure), so all requests will be to the cloud

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is better than option 1. But, with respect, it's still not good.

Never never store comma-separated lists of things in columns of data. If you do you'll be sorry. (They're very costly to search.)

You want something like this.  Three tables, one for users, another for services, and a so-called JOIN table to establish a many-to-many relationship between the two.

```
+-----------+    +-------------+     +-----------+
|user       |    |user_service |     |service    |
+-----------+    +-------------+     +-----------+
|user_id    +--->|user_id      |<----+service_id |
|givennamee |    |service_id   |     |name       |
|surname    |    +-------------+     +-----------+
|is_active  |
+-----------+
```

Each row in `user_service` means a user is authorized to use that service. To authorize a user, INSERT a row. To revoke authorization, DELETE the row.

To find out whethe a user can use a service, use this query.

```sql
SELECT user.user_id 
  FROM user
  JOIN user_service USING (user_id)
  JOIN service USING (service_id)
 WHERE user.givenname = 'Bill' AND user.surname='Gates'
   AND service.name = 'CharityNavigator'
   AND user.is_active > 0;
```

If your query returns the `user_id` then the chosen user may use the chosen service.

To get a list of the services for each user, use this query.

```sql
SELECT user.user_id, user.givenname, user.surname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(service.name) service_names
  FROM user
  JOIN user_service USING (user_id)
  JOIN service USING (service_id)
 WHERE user.is_active > 0
 GROUP BY user.user_id
```

Some explanation:
It's almost always best to build tables with rows for things like your services in them, rather than columns or comma-separated lists in columns.  Why?

1. You can add new services -- as many as you want -- years from now without reworking your database code.
2. DBMSs, including MySQL, work well with JOIN operations.
3. Doing `WHERE commalist_column SOMEHOW_CONTAINS (some_id)` is disgustingly inefficient in most relational database management systems. Doing `WHERE column = some_id` is far more efficient because it can use an index.
4. Rows with fewer columns, in general, work better than rows with more columns.
5. It's **far cheaper** in production to add rows to databases than it is to add columns. Adding columns means altering table definitions. That operation can require downtime.

When you use columns for things like your services, you're creating a closed system. When you use rows, your system is open-ended.

May I suggest you read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)? Don't be intimidated by all the CS jargon. Just look at some examples of how to normalize various databases.

And maybe read about [entity-relationship database modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)?

**Edit** On the advice of a commenter, I suggest you make the primary key of your `user_service` table to contain both columns `(user_id, service_id)`. I also suggest you make a reverse index with both columns `(service_id, user_id)` so your queries can look things up quickly starting with service as well as user. Your table definitions might look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    givenname VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    is_active TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';

CREATE TABLE service (
    service_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (service_id)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci';

CREATE TABLE user_service (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    service_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, service_id),
    INDEX reverse_index (service_id, user_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_service 
               FOREIGN KEY (service_id)
               REFERENCES service (service_id)
               ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_user 
               FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
               REFERENCES user (user_id)
               ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

With this primary key if you attempt to INSERT a duplicate authorization for a user for a service, the dbms rejects it.

Be sure to use the same 'INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`data type for`user_id`and`service_id` in those tables.

This is a very common database design pattern: it's the canonical way of creating a many-to-many relationship between rows of two different tables.

Comment: Good explanation. As an additional info for the author of the question I would also recommend to make primary key from `user_id + service_id` in JOIN table `user_service`. 
This is good practice as you won't be able to insert duplicated records, as well as you may not really need to have Id column with no role.

Comment: Good point @tzu-ax, thank you.  Please see my edit.

Comment: @O.Jones excelent. What I don't understand is. U said the option2 is better. Then u say "Never never store comma-separated lists of things in columns of data", but that's is option2, option 1 is multiple columns for different serv.Let's see if I understand u, u would make 3 tables, 1 for user, another to join user/service, and another for services (this would put the services identified with an id, one for each row). In the table of users_serv you would put the user id as a row, and several columns with the different services id that the user has (but not in an array, but in different columns)

Answer (score 0):

**A 3rd way**  (most frugal on space)

See the `SET` datatype.  It allows for saying which combination of those 6 servs apply.

`INT UNSIGNED` (of a suitable size) is another way to have a "set".

SET or TINYINT takes only 1 byte to represent up to 8 items.

Your 6 column choice takes 6 bytes.

The "{serv1,... }" might be a `VARCHAR`, averaging 10-20 bytes.

So, My suggestions are clearly aimed at saving space.  But maybe that is not important?  Do you have millions or rows?  Do you have more tnan 64 "servs"?  (There is a limit of 64 on SET and BIGINT UNSIGNED.)

**But Which?**

Is the question about coding?  Well, any method is going to take some effort to split the bits/columns/string apart to build the buttons on the screen.  Probably a similar amount of effort and probably less than the effort to build the screen.  Ditto for performance.

I highly recommend you pick two solutions and implement both.  You will discover

- How similar they are in performance, amount code, etc.
- How insignificant the question is.
- How much extra stuff you have learned about databases.
- How easy it is to "try" and "throw away" another way to do something.
- How the latency, performance, etc, differences are insignificant.  (This is what we are really answering for you.)

**The bigger picture**

You have pointed out one use for this data structure.  I worry that there are, or will be, other uses for this data structure.  And that something else is the real determinant of which approach is best.  (At that point, you can happily resurrect the thrown away version!)

**A 4th way**

JSON.  But it would be more verbose (take more space) than your VARCHAR way.  It may or may not be easier to work with -- this depends on *the rest of the requirements*.